# categorical data to be dummified and aggregated

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation

I have the following dataset where X1 is the date of test done, X2 is the results of tests having 45 levels and x3 is the test name

```
X1          X2   X3
20.04.2017  AA  1256(NB)
20.04.2017  AA  1257(NB)
20.04.2017  AA  1258(LM)
20.04.2017  LL  1257(NB)
23.07.2017  LL  1256(NB)
23.07.2017  LL  1258(LM)
```

I am trying to transform the above data to

```
Date         X3        AA   LL
20.04.2017  1256(NB)    1   1
20.04.2017  1257(NB)    1   1
20.04.2017  1258(LM)    1   0
23.07.2017  1258(LM)    0   1
```

I was able to create the dummy columns for AA & LL using 'pd.get_dummies' but the aggregation on the basis of X3 column is not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be using `get_dummies` + `sum`:

```
df.set_index(['X1', 'X3']).X2\
      .str.get_dummies().sum(level=[0, 1]).reset_index()

           X1        X3  AA  LL
0  20.04.2017  1256(NB)   1   0
1  20.04.2017  1257(NB)   1   1
2  20.04.2017  1258(LM)   1   0
3  23.07.2017  1256(NB)   0   1
4  23.07.2017  1258(LM)   0   1
```

Comment: Thank you!! @COLDSPEED, but if the levels grow in number to like 45 levels, do I need to write (level =[0,1.......,44]) ???

Comment: @Devesh You can pass a range: `level=np.arange(45)`

Comment: @COLDSPEED thank you for the clarification...and what if the numbers of levels are unknown?

Comment: @Devesh it isn’t hard to query df.index and count the number of levels.

Comment: I Fixed it by using df.set_index(['X1','X3']).['X2'].str.get_dummies.....                   but I get another error raise AssertionError('Level %s not in index' % str(level))
AssertionError: Level [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45] not in index

Comment: @Devesh while I sympathise with your situation, you did not make this clear in your question, and hence my answer did not account for that. Now that you have unaccepted my answer, I’m even more disinclined to help you. You could either open a new question or deal with the issue yourself. Your choice.

Comment: @COLDSPEED I apologise for unticking, it was by mistake as I was trying a few options. I did not notice the unticking ( unaccepting). Yiur solution was very helpful in providing an insight and path, its just that I needed help with 45 levels

Comment: @Devesh Please open a new question and explain your problem in a bit more detail... I can provide you with an answer (comments aren't a great place to answer questions)